# Remove null values from java array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to remove null values from a array that is converted from a csv string.

This is what i'm trying to do.

```
public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String commaSeparated = "item1,null,item1,null,item3";
        String [] items = commaSeparated.split(",");

        String[] result = removeNull(items);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

     public static String[] removeNull(String[] items) {
            ArrayList<String> aux = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String elem : items) {
                if (elem != null) {
                    aux.add(elem);
                }
            }

            return (String[]) aux.toArray(new String[aux.size()]);
        }

}
```

I still get the output as below which still has the null values. Can you please point me what is wrong with this

```
[item1, null, item1, null, item3]
```

Comment: The string "null" is different from a reference being `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (elem != null)
```

to

```
if (!elem.equals("null"))
```

The `.split` function returns an array of strings, so those elements that you expected to be `null` are not actually, they are `"null"` strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your `removeNulls()` method does in fact remove null `Strings`, but remember when you are doing `String.split`, you are actually creating a non-null `String` whose value happens to be "null".

So change this...

```
if (elem != null) {
```

To this, to account for "null"...

```
if (elem != null && !elem.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
```

Comment: Consider lower casing the `elem` if OP wants to get rid of `"NULL"` or `"Null"`

Comment: Good call. Changed `equals` to `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 0):

`removeNull(String[])` works fine, it is the test that is broken. Consider creating test input like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] items = {"item1",null,"item1",null,"item3"};

    String[] result = removeNull(items);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

As an aside, this is a good place to think about generics. What if you wanted your method signature to look like this `T[] removeNull(T[] input)`. That might present you with some interesting options and a more versatile final product.

Answer (score 0):

with streams:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String commaSeparated = "item1,null,item1,null,item3";
    String[] items = commaSeparated.split(",");

    String[] result = Arrays.stream(items)
            .filter(s -> s != null && !s.equals("null"))
            .toArray(String[]::new);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```